# About a 1/2 of a row of keys have stopped working on my Lenovo Yoga 520 laptop

Tags: keyboard

My <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> ,<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> keys have suddenly stopped working on my Lenovo Yoga 520 laptop. I tried to remove them but didn't find any dust underneath them, and each one of them was clean, what can I do?

Comment: Is it still under warranty? If so, send it in for warranty repair. Otherwise, if a specific series of keys like this is failing that could mean a common connection in the keyboard is affected in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Try an external USB keyboard.

- If that keyboard works, then the physical keyboard is broken. Either stay with the USB keyboard, or get the old one fixed. Replacements are available for US$20 - US$40.
- If the external keyboard has the same issue, it's a software problem.

Answer (score 0):

All the keys that stopped working are all in the same row of the keyboard. This pattern does not appear to be coincidental. All the keys in the same row stopped working can be caused by water that was spilled on that part of the keyboard which conducts electricity between the contacts of the circuit.

To fix this problem allow the keyboard to dry in direct sunlight for a few hours during the day when the temperature is hottest. This will cause the spilled water to evaporate. Another tip is to position the keyboard at an small angle when it is drying, so that if there is any water in the keyboard it will flow sideways to one side of the keyboard away from the keys that stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me, it was the entire bottom row. The issue was the ribbon cable which connected the keyboard to the MB had been pulled slightly loose (due to a swollen battery putting pressure on the cable). I reseated it and locked it back in place and good to go.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have Fn Lck on your Lenovo keyboard?  I do on mine.  Toggle Fn-Lck back and forth and see if that changes your keys/

Also look in Control Panel, Accessibility features and turn any of these settings off.

Restart and check again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/912446)

Comment: Similar conditions at clients have sometimes been fixed this way which is why I suggested it. Of course,, it may not work here.

Comment: "Do you have Fn Lck on your Lenovo keyboard?" is a question that belongs in a comment to the author, not an answer, commentary submitted as an answer is going to receive downvotes.

Comment: The number pad on some laptops uses the keys on the other side of the keyboard, and only thee across. No keyboard I'm familiar with uses the left side of the keyboard for the number pad keys.

Comment: It’s OK for an answer to begin with a question if it goes on to provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @Scott - Perhaps if the quality of the entire answer was better but this answer is nothing but an educated guess, i.e. "turn any of these settings off" is unclear since it does not specify which settings to turn off.